# One-line conditionals in Python (C++ style)

Tags: python, lambda, conditional-statements

I tried to replicate C++ style single line conditionals in Python like so:

I have a function defined : `isPalidrome (mystr)` - returns `True` if `mystr` is a palidrome,`False` otherwise.  The function works.

Now I have a simple main function like so:

```
mystr =''
isitapalindromealready = lambda : if isPalindrome(mystr) ==True:    return "" else return 'not'
while mystr != 'quit':
    mystr = input("enter a string: ")
    print  ('{} is {} a palindrome'.format(mystr, isitapalindromealready())
```

But i get an Syntax error -

```
  File "scratch1.py", line 45
    isitapalindromealready = lambda : if isPalindrome(mystr) ==True:    return "" else return 'not'
                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I did check a similar thread that comes very close to replicating my logic above (it just does not call the lambda as a function anywhere).

[Conditional statement in a one line lambda function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772617/conditional-statement-in-a-one-line-lambda-function-in-python)

However, none of the answers explain WHY it is a syntax error. If you ignore PEP 8, the syntax is valid unless you you cannot include `else` in the same line as `if`.

Any help, options, alternative considerations ? 
BTW: I wrote this simple program to check on this feature for reducing the logic size of much larger modules. I know very well that I can get away with checking if its a palindrome within the `isPalindrome` function. Thats not the point of my question.

Comment: @DYZ: Note that your previous edit invalidated the error message posted, so I rolled it back.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 3):

You can fit your conditionals on one line, definitely. This is how you do it in python.

```
isitapalindromealready = lambda x: "" if isPalindrome(x) else "not"
```

Sure, you can have lambdas work with global variables, but that is not how I would recommend doing it. A well written lambda should be a pure function, meaning you would pass the parameter to it. Additionally, the `lambda` needs no `return` as it is implied. Now, you must call your lambda as such:

```
isitapalindromealready(mystr)
```

---

```
isitapalindromealready = lambda x: "" if isPalindrome(x) else "not"
while mystr != 'quit':
    mystr = input("enter a string: ")
    print  ('{} is {} a palindrome'.format(mystr, isitapalindromealready(mystr))
```