# how to fix lambda and map functions in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I want to create a set of values that can divide a specific number. In my code below, I want factors of number 12.

```py
x=12
a=set(map(lambda i:i if(x%i==0),range(1,x+1)))
print(a)
```

I expected output to be {1,2,3,4,6,12}.

but i have got some error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-18-7f73bd4c5148>", line 2
    a=set(map(lambda i:i if(x%i==0),range(1,x+1)))
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: I think your lambda is supposed to be `lambda i : x%i==0`. What you have now doesn't make sense. And I think you should be using `filter` instead of `map`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your lambda is supposed to be `lambda i : x%i==0`. What you have now doesn't make sense. And I think you should be using [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) instead of `map`.

```
>>> x = 12
>>> a = set(filter(lambda i:x%i==0, range(1,x+1)))
>>> print(a)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are confusing `lambda` notation with list/set comprehension notation. The correct way using `lambda` and `filter` (not `map`) has already been shown, so here's a version using a set comprehension:

```
>>> x = 12
>>> {i for i in range(1, x+1) if x % i == 0}
{1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 12}
```

As you see, the `i if ...` is present here (although distributed over different parts of the expression), but not in the `lambda`.

Answer (score 0):

try 
`a=set(filter(lambda i: True  if(x%i==0) else False,range(1,x+1)))`

The condition in lambda function should be defined as explained here:
[Conditional statement in a one line lambda function in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772617/conditional-statement-in-a-one-line-lambda-function-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a generator or function instead of a lambda as they are not [PEP-8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008) compliant and typically make logic more complex. Using a generator will also allow you to save memory if you are going to be making very long sequences.

Example generator

```py
gen = (x for x in range(1, 1000000000) if 12 % x == 0)
```